# Themes with Wordpress Rest API and Multisite

Tags: wordpress, api, rest, redirect

How can I manage to have themes in the WordPress Theme folder that will not render the content from Wordpress directly but with the WordPress Rest API? I'd like to have my custom routing inside each theme. For example I want to render the the file www.exmaple.com/wp-content/themes/example-theme/subdirectory/about-us.html as www.example.com/about-us.html

Ist this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the JSON API Restful plugin and add a controller in the theme with:

```
add_filter('json_api_controllers', 'add_yourcontrollername_controller' );
add_filter('json_api_yourcontrollername_controller_path', 'get_yourcontrollername_path' );

function add_yourcontrollername_controller($controllers) {
    $controllers[] = 'yourcontrollername';
    return $controllers;
}

function get_yourcontrollername_path() {
    return __DIR__ . "yourcontrollername.php";
}
```

Inside the controllers you could setup rewrite rules or do something else.

More Documentation about the API found [here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/other_notes/)